# Find the values where the tangent has slope 1 for the parametric curve $x=2t^3$ and $y=4+16t-10t^2$.

Tags: calculus, parametric

> $x=2t^3$ and $y=4+16t-10t^2$

First find the slope and set it equal to one:

$m=\dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} =\dfrac{16-20t}{6t^2}$

Setting equal to one:

$\dfrac{16t-20t}{6t}=1$ Factor out the 4 on the top and reduce coefficients:

$\dfrac{4(4-5t)}{6t^2}=1 \to \frac{2(4-5t)}{3t^2}=1$ Move the one over:

$\dfrac{2(4-5t)}{3t^2}-1=0$ Multiply both sides by $3t^2$:

$2(4-5t)-3t^2=0$ Factor back in the two:

$-3t^2-10t+8$ Now use the quadratic formula:

$\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ Which works out to:

$\dfrac{10 \pm \sqrt{100 - (-12)(8)}}{-6} \to \dfrac{10 \pm \sqrt{100-(-96)}}{-6} \to \dfrac{10 \pm \sqrt{196}}{-6}$ Simplified gives values of t:

$t=\dfrac{10+14}{-6}=-4$

$t=\dfrac{10-14}{-6}=\frac{2}{3}$

When $t=\frac{2}{3}$:

$x=2(\frac{2}{3}^3) = .2962962963$

$y=4+16(\frac{2}{3})-10(\frac{2}{3})^2=8.000000003$

I get the correct value when $t=-4$ so I just left it out. I don't see how my answer here could be wrong but the computer rejected it. Did I miss something?

Comment: There is something wrong with your arithmetic.  $2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{16}{27} \not= 0.\overline{296}$, and $4+16\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-10\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{92}{9} \not= 8$.

Comment: do you mean $$x=2\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Probably, but either way the decimal result is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I mean what you have for x

Comment: It accepted those values you gave but only fraction form the program doesn't accept decimals